# How to only display current and valid data from 2 tables in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have these two tables:

Table imp_source:

```
Product     class       seq
  5           5          1
  5           3          2
  5           16         3
  8           1          1
  8           4          2
```

Table imp_update:

```
Product     class       seq
  5           6          4
  8           1          6
  8           4          2
  8           23         3
  9           3          1
```

I need to write a query to have this result:

```
Product     class       seq
  5           5          1
  5           3          2
  5           16         3
  5           6          4
  8           1          6
  8           4          2
  8           23         3
  9           3          1
```

- All values of imp_update
- The values of imp_source when there is no update for seq column of a product/class combination.

**Update 1:**

As you can see, the row in imp_source is not in result

```
  product  class    seq    
    8       1       1
```

Because in imp_update the seq column of product/class combination is updated:

```
product   class    seq
    8       1       6
```

Comment: what is your RDBMS ?

Comment: My Db is Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a union approach here with the help of exists logic:

```sql
SELECT s.Product, s.class, s.seq
FROM imp_source s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM imp_update u
                  WHERE u.Product = s.Product AND u.class = s.class)
UNION ALL
SELECT Product, class, seq
FROM imp_update
ORDER BY Product;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link above]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
SELECT product,class,MAX(seq)
FROM
(
    SELECT x.*, 1 as x FROM imp_source x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x.*, 2 as x FROM imp_update x
) z
GROUP BY product,class
```

to me

If seq can go down as well as up, then perhaps:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    product,
    class,
    LAST_VALUE(seq) OVER(PARTITION BY product, class ORDER BY x ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as seq
FROM
(
    SELECT x.*, 1 as x FROM imp_source x
    UNION ALL
    SELECT x.*, 2 as x FROM imp_update x
) z
```

Comment: I think that might be false with max. Because the Update for Seq is not always a a greater value.

Comment: It wasn't immediately obvious from the question data. I added an alternative form for that case

Comment: I tried with yours too and I got ORA-30484 Error.

Comment: I missed the "OVER" keyword; typo corrected, thanks!